# Element $variable is resolved only by name without use of explicit in Sass PhpStorm

Tags: css, sass, phpstorm

I'm new in Sass ( SCSS ). In Sass I follow `7-1 pattern` and currently I am using Phpstorm as IDE.

I import all my `_<name>.scss` files in one main file called `main.scss` file.

**Problem**

I define my color variables in `_variables.scss` file but when I use it in other .scss file, PhpStorm gives error like

> Element 'gutter-horizontal' (**variable name**) is resolved only by name without use of explicit imports more...

I also give screenshot of my IDE so, you know structure of my folder.

[image]

I check all over internet but I can't find any solution, this is not duplicate question of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44415965/importing-bootstrap-in-less-not-working-element-is-resolved-only-by-name) ok !!

### BUT

When I import my `_variables.scss` in my scss files, error gone.

[image]

### Question

So, do I need to import `vaiables.scss` in my all scss files or I done something wrong ?

I don't understand this problem coming from where ? Sass or PhpStorm ?

**variables.scss**

```
// COLORS

$color-primary: #55c57a;
$color-primary-light: #7ed56f;
$color-primary-dark: #28b485;
$color-gray-dark: #777;

$color-black: #000;
$color-white: #fff;

// GRID

$grid-width: 114rem;
$gutter-vertical: 8rem;
$gutter-horizontal: 6rem;
```

**main.scss**

```
@charset "UTF-8";

@import 'abstracts/variables';
@import 'abstracts/functions';
@import 'abstracts/mixins';

@import 'base/animations';
@import 'base/base';
@import 'base/typography';
@import 'base/utilities';

@import 'components/buttons';

@import 'layout/header';
@import 'layout/grid';

@import 'pages/home';
```

Comment: Just ignore the error from PHPStorm

Comment: any specific reason ?

Comment: It's just to let you know. As long as you don't get a real error from SCSS than you're good to go. The error isn't even there if you'd use an editor like vsc

Comment: ohk, so what i do to solve that error in phpstorm, just ignore ?

Comment: Yes, like I said

Comment: IDE does not know that variables from your `_variables.scss` will be used in `_grid.scss` via your `main.scss` (because it's used indirectly). You can read a bit more in this comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-5771#focus=streamItem-27-433015-0-0. As mentioned by Mikepote, that inspection can be disabled.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

No, you're doing it correctly. Have one main.scss file and make sure your variables are the *first* thing that you import (otherwise you will run into undefined variable issues in other files). You do not need to re-import your variables for each file as long as they are all included in your main.scss file.

I normally ignore this PhpStorm error, or you can turn it off:

- Go to `File` -> `Settings`
- `Editor` -> `Inspections` in the left panel
- `Sass/SCSS` in the right panel
- uncheck `Missing import` (or `Resolved by name only` on older versions)

Comment: Is it a bad practice ? like disabling an eslint check ?

Comment: @MaximeP No, I wouldnt consider it bad practice, it's only there to warn you that PhpStorm cant resolve the files necessary for the SASS to compile. It has nothing to do with coding standards.

Answer (score 3):

In GoLand version 2021 the item `Resolved by name only` was renamed:

1. `Preferences` -> `Editor` -> `Inspections` -> `Sass/SCSS` (in the right panel)
2. Uncheck `Missing Import`